# Unexpected token ILLEGAL while trying to run a javascript example about Protractor automation

Tags: selenium, automation, jasmine, protractor

While trying to run this example about [Protractor Automation](http://www.joecolantonio.com/2015/04/30/how-to-get-started-with-protractor-automation-example/) 
when I tap protractor conf.js in cmd I got the following error

```
exports.config = {
          directConnect: true,

          // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
          capabilities: {
            'browserName': 'chrome'
          },

          // Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
          framework: 'jasmine',

          // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directly when
          // protractor is called.
          specs: ['joe_spec.js'],

          // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
          jasmineNodeOpts: {
            defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
          }
        };

C:\Users\Emna\Desktop\example>protractor conf.js
Using ChromeDriver directly...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[launcher] Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at C:\Users\Emna\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:71:5
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Jasmine.loadSpecs (C:\Users\Emna\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:70:18)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 100
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the conf.js file? Thanks

Comment: ok, it's done. Thanks

Comment: Here is the joe_spec.js file : 


describe(‘Enter text in element on Protractor Example page’, function() {

it (“to check that text entered in text box displays on page”,function() {
browser.get(“http://www.joecolantonio.com/ProtractorExample.html”);
element(by.model(“joeAngularText”)).sendKeys(“Joe Colantonio”);
element(by.binding(“joeAngularText”)).getText().then(function(text){
console.log(text);
});
});
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go this will work copy, paste this example code and run it:

```
describe('Enter text in element on Protractor Example page', function() {

    it ('to check that text entered in text box displays on page',function() {
        browser.get('http://www.joecolantonio.com/ProtractorExample.html');
            element(by.model('joeAngularText')).sendKeys('Joe Colantonio');
        element(by.binding('joeAngularText')).getText().then(function(text){
            console.log(text);
        });
    });
});
```

The problem is the characters you are using in your description file:
both ‘ and “ are dodgy characters which it doesnt like.. if you replace them with ' and " it works... I just tested both and I got the same error message when I used your code as what you get.. But if I change to '  and " then the error goes away

Comment: You are most welcome, Im glad to be of assistance :)

Comment: I'm beginner this is my first example with angular JS and protractor :)